Firewall on an Android hotspot
So my idea for a project is a firewall for Android hotspot. Like on routers you can block access to certain websites, I want to implement it in Android. In settings, system can only limit number of connected users. There aren't advanced options (I'm using Android 13).
So if I for example block instagram on my firewall, the devices connected to my mobile hotspot won't be able to access it. Like a parental control.
I know I probably must root my phone for this, but it's no problem. The answers I read were old and I didn't find any specific instructions. People recommended using hosts file or iptables but I'm not sure it would work if the request isn't directly from my phone. Downloaded a few blockers but they also fail, or doesn't even have options to do this.
So the main question is, is it possible ? I wanted to ask before I start digging in my phone.
Information I found: Is there a way to set up a firewall on mobile hotspot to block incoming connections?
https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidQuestions/comments/ihjrbv/mobile_hotspot_allow_only_one_website/
How to use iptables in an Android application
Create wifi hotspot but block access certain domains
How to block a particular website?
How to Block/Filter Sites on Mobile Data Connection (Preferably using DNS Server)
How to block access to a website?
